# How do you deal with arrays that are written like objects in gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm writing a client for an API that gives me JSON data in this way:

```
"Thing": {
        "0": {
        ...
        },
        "1": {
        ...
        },
        "2": {
        ...
        }
}
```

Because I'm attempting to put this in a List, I'm getting the error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

I don't want to have to add a HashMap to my Java object, I'd like to figure out a way to get gson to convert it properly. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: iterate over all objects?

Comment: Array should start with `[`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the object in an HashMap and after you can convert this to a List:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> yourMapFromJSON = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(yourMapFromJSON.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your model contain array instead of Map you haw two options.

- parse the JSON into Map, and then retrieve the values from it.
- create a specific parser for this case.